# .bat file to install microsoft office from a network location that is password protected

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a .bat file that will automatically run a setup file to install Microsoft office, but the problem I am having is that when I map the network drive it prompts me for a username and password from the device, but I d not know how to have the script either automatically log in or to at least prompt me for the password. Any Ideas?

This is what I have so far:

```
net use x: \\000.00.000.00\images\Service\microsoft\Office 2010 64-bit
START "Office 64-bit" x: "setup.exe"
net use x: /delete
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
net use x: \\server\folder /user:domain\user password
```